# Chrome Extension to Set Local Homepage?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Since it seems none exist, I'm trying to make a chrome extension to set my New Tab page to a local .html file. Here's what I have so far:

```
{
  "name": "MyHomepage",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Set an HTML page as your New Tab page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "/Users/shortname/Documents/Home.html"
  }
}
```

However, when I load a new page, it gives me this:
No webpage was found for the web address: chrome-extension://(gibberish)//Users/shortname/Documents/Home.html
It seems Chrome is sandboxing my extension somehow. Is there a way to let it access my local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's extension API does not allow for direct reading or writing from/to disk.

If you want to do that you'll have to use a NPAPI plugin in your extension:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Comment: NPAPI is being phased out and doesn't supports by Google Chrome now

Answer (score 1):

You can use Native Messaging instead of NPAPI https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging